# Revit 2015 slow to load for one user on workstation

Tags: autocad, revit

I'm really new to troubleshooting Revit and was hoping someone could help me identify why Revit is taking so long to open.

Problem and testing:

User A opens Revit 2014 or 2015 on PC it takes about 21min to open.
User B opens Rebit 2014 or 2014 on PC it takes about 1min to open.

I have attached the journal file below showing where the time delay is happening for User A. Apologies for all the info, but not sure what is required.

12:16 - 12:37 is the timestamp show below.

```
'C 12-Nov-2015 12:16:02.067;   0:< MFCApp::testMSAA 
       ' 0:< Revit Graphics Information 
       ' 0:<    Current Mode : DirectX Hardware 
       ' 0:<    Use Hardware: ON 
       ' 0:<    Use Overlays : ON 
       'C 12-Nov-2015 12:16:02.067;   0:< postConditionalWarnings 
       'C 12-Nov-2015 12:16:02.067;   0:< giveAtomRegistrationWarnings 
       'C 12-Nov-2015 12:16:02.067;   0:< warnings->consumeAll 
       'C 12-Nov-2015 12:16:02.067;   0:< Process result of DebugModes-Changed Task Dialog 
       'C 12-Nov-2015 12:16:02.067;   0:< isMaterialLibraryAvailable 
       'C 12-Nov-2015 12:16:02.067;   0:< start up warnings for AddIns 
       ' 0:<  <-DesktopMFCApp::doStartupWarnings 
       ' 0:<  <-desktop InitNativeInstance 
       ' 0:<  ->desktop InitManagedInstance 
       ' 1:< API_SUCCESS { An external server has been registered.: ServiceId(d8b95737-f943-414c-9ad7-86785bf1acbc);
   ServerId(bbe27f6b-e887-4f68-9152-1e664dad29c3); Name(IFC exporter);
   VendorId(IFCX); Description(IFC open source exporter) } 
       ' 1:< API_SUCCESS { An external server has been registered.: ServiceId(98d317e2-e943-4cc0-a3da-2edf32a5d942);
   ServerId(88743f28-a2e1-4935-949d-4db7a724a150); Name(IFC importer);
   VendorId(IFCX); Description(IFC open source importer) } 
       ' 0:<  <-desktop InitManagedInstance 
       ' 0:< ::1:: Delta VM: Avail -134 -> 8386686 MB, Used +11 -> 479 MB, Peak +8 -> 481 MB; RAM: Avail -52 -> 151108 MB, Used +20 -> 400
   MB, Peak +17 -> 401 MB 
       'C 12-Nov-2015 12:16:02.896;   0:< appPriv idle 
       ' 0:< OPERATING SYSTEM INFORMATION:  
       ' 0:<    BuildNumber : 7601 
       ' 0:<    BuildType : Multiprocessor Free 
       ' 0:<    Caption : Microsoft Windows 7 Professional  
       ' 0:<    CodeSet : 1252 
       ' 0:<    CountryCode : 44 
       ' 0:<    CSDVersion : Service Pack 1 
       ' 0:<    FreePhysicalMemory : 154729440 
       ' 0:<    FreeSpaceInPagingFiles : 819200 
       ' 0:<    FreeVirtualMemory : 147055088 
       ' 0:<    MaxProcessMemorySize : 8589934464 
       ' 0:<    OSLanguage : 1033 
       ' 0:<    OSType : 18 
       ' 0:<    ServicePackMajorVersion : 1 
       ' 0:<    ServicePackMinorVersion : 0 
       ' 0:<    TotalVirtualMemorySize : 202143956 
       ' 0:<    TotalVisibleMemorySize : 201326592 
       ' 0:<    Version : 6.1.7601 
       ' 0:<    Process affinity mask : FFFFFFFF 
       ' 0:<    System affinity mask : FFFFFFFF 
       ' 0:< PROCESSOR INFORMATION:  
       ' 0:<    AddressWidth : 64 
       ' 0:<    Architecture : 9 
       ' 0:<    Availability : 3 
       ' 0:<    Caption : Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2 
       ' 0:<    CurrentClockSpeed : 2601 
       ' 0:<    DataWidth : 64 
       ' 0:<    Description : Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2 
       ' 0:<    Family : 179 
       ' 0:<    L2CacheSize : 3072 
       ' 0:<    Level : 6 
       ' 0:<    Manufacturer : GenuineIntel 
       ' 0:<    MaxClockSpeed : 2601 
       ' 0:<    Name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz 
       ' 0:<    ProcessorType : 3 
       ' 0:<    Revision : 16130 
       ' 0:<    Role : CPU 
       ' 0:<    SocketDesignation : CPU0 
       ' 0:<    StatusInfo : 3 
       ' 0:<    Version :  
       ' 0:< PROCESSOR INFORMATION:  
       ' 0:<    AddressWidth : 64 
       ' 0:<    Architecture : 9 
       ' 0:<    Availability : 3 
       ' 0:<    Caption : Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2 
       ' 0:<    CurrentClockSpeed : 2601 
       ' 0:<    DataWidth : 64 
       ' 0:<    Description : Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2 
       ' 0:<    Family : 179 
       ' 0:<    L2CacheSize : 3072 
       ' 0:<    Level : 6 
       ' 0:<    Manufacturer : GenuineIntel 
       ' 0:<    MaxClockSpeed : 2601 
       ' 0:<    Name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz 
       ' 0:<    ProcessorType : 3 
       ' 0:<    Revision : 16130 
       ' 0:<    Role : CPU 
       ' 0:<    SocketDesignation : CPU1 
       ' 0:<    StatusInfo : 3 
       ' 0:<    Version :  
       ' 0:< VIDEO CONTROLLER INFORMATION:  
       ' 0:<    AdapterCompatibility : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
       ' 0:<    AdapterDACType : Internal DAC(400MHz) 
       ' 0:<    AdapterRAM : -1048576 
       ' 0:<    Caption : AMD FirePro W5100 (FireGL V) 
       ' 0:<    CurrentBitsPerPixel : 32 
       ' 0:<    CurrentHorizontalResolution : 640 
       ' 0:<    CurrentNumberOfColors : 4294967296 
       ' 0:<    CurrentRefreshRate : 59 
       ' 0:<    CurrentVerticalResolution : 480 
       ' 0:<    Description : AMD FirePro W5100 (FireGL V) 
       ' 0:<    DriverDate : 20150124000000.000000-000 
       ' 0:<    DriverVersion : 14.301.1019.0 
       ' 0:<    MaxRefreshRate : 59 
       ' 0:<    MinRefreshRate : 59 
       ' 0:<    Monochrome : 0 
       ' 0:<    Name : AMD FirePro W5100 (FireGL V) 
       ' 0:<    VideoArchitecture : 5 
       ' 0:<    VideoMemoryType : 2 
       ' 0:<    VideoModeDescription : 640 x 480 x 4294967296 colors 
       ' 0:<    VideoProcessor : AMD Radeon Graphics Processor SDI (0x6649) 
       ' 0:< ::1:: Delta VM: Avail -2 -> 8386684 MB, Used 479 MB; RAM: Avail -29 -> 151079 MB, Used +1 -> 401 MB, Peak +1 -> 403 MB 
       ' 0:< PRINTER INFORMATION:  
       ' 0:<    Caption : Fax (redirected 31) 
       ' 0:<    Default : 0 
       ' 0:<    DeviceID : Fax (redirected 31) 
       ' 0:<    Direct : 0 
       ' 0:<    DriverName : Microsoft Shared Fax Driver 
       ' 0:<    EnableBIDI : 0 
       ' 0:<    EnableDevQueryPrint : 0 
       ' 0:<    HorizontalResolution : 200 
       ' 0:<    Local : -1 
       ' 0:<    Name : Fax (redirected 31) 
       ' 0:<    Network : 0 
       ' 0:<    PortName : TS275 
       ' 0:<    PrintJobDataType : RAW 
       ' 0:<    PrintProcessor : winprint 
       ' 0:<    RawOnly : 0 
       ' 0:<    Shared : 0 
       ' 0:<    SpoolEnabled : -1 
       ' 0:<    VerticalResolution : 200 
       ' 0:< PRINTER INFORMATION:  
       ' 0:<    Caption : Send To OneNote 2013 
       ' 0:<    Default : 0 
       ' 0:<    DeviceID : Send To OneNote 2013 
       ' 0:<    Direct : 0 
       ' 0:<    DriverName : Send to Microsoft OneNote 15 Driver 
       ' 0:<    EnableBIDI : 0 
       ' 0:<    EnableDevQueryPrint : 0 
       ' 0:<    HorizontalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Local : -1 
       ' 0:<    Name : Send To OneNote 2013 
       ' 0:<    Network : 0 
       ' 0:<    PortName : nul: 
       ' 0:<    PrintJobDataType : RAW 
       ' 0:<    PrintProcessor : winprint 
       ' 0:<    RawOnly : 0 
       ' 0:<    Shared : 0 
       ' 0:<    SpoolEnabled : -1 
       ' 0:<    VerticalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Caption : RICOH HEMEL 
       ' 0:<    Default : 0 
       ' 0:<    DeviceID : RICOH HEMEL 
       ' 0:<    Direct : 0 
       ' 0:<    DriverName : RICOH MP C4503 PCL 6 
       ' 0:<    EnableBIDI : -1 
       ' 0:<    EnableDevQueryPrint : 0 
       ' 0:<    HorizontalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Local : -1 
       ' 0:<    Name : RICOH HEMEL 
       ' 0:<    Network : 0 
       ' 0:<    PortName : TCP_192.168.16.20 
       ' 0:<    PrintJobDataType : RAW 
       ' 0:<    PrintProcessor : winprint 
       ' 0:<    RawOnly : 0 
       ' 0:<    Shared : 0 
       ' 0:<    SpoolEnabled : -1 
       ' 0:<    VerticalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Caption : LONDON RICOH 
       ' 0:<    Default : -1 
       ' 0:<    DeviceID : LONDON RICOH 
       ' 0:<    Direct : 0 
       ' 0:<    DriverName : RICOH MP C2503 PCL 6 
       ' 0:<    EnableBIDI : -1 
       ' 0:<    EnableDevQueryPrint : 0 
       ' 0:<    HorizontalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Local : -1 
       ' 0:<    Name : LONDON RICOH 
       ' 0:<    Network : 0 
       ' 0:<    PortName : TCP_192.168.3.20 
       ' 0:<    PrintJobDataType : RAW 
       ' 0:<    PrintProcessor : winprint 
       ' 0:<    RawOnly : 0 
       ' 0:<    Shared : 0 
       ' 0:<    SpoolEnabled : -1 
       ' 0:<    VerticalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Caption : HP Designjet T520 
       ' 0:<    Default : 0 
       ' 0:<    DeviceID : HP Designjet T520 
       ' 0:<    Direct : 0 
       ' 0:<    DriverName : HP Designjet T520 36in 
       ' 0:<    EnableBIDI : 0 
       ' 0:<    EnableDevQueryPrint : 0 
       ' 0:<    HorizontalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Local : -1 
       ' 0:<    Name : HP Designjet T520 
       ' 0:<    Network : 0 
       ' 0:<    PortName : 192.168.3.21 
       ' 0:<    PrintJobDataType : RAW 
       ' 0:<    PrintProcessor : hpippb4x 
       ' 0:<    RawOnly : 0 
       ' 0:<    Shared : 0 
       ' 0:<    SpoolEnabled : -1 
       ' 0:<    VerticalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Caption : Glasgow-HP-colour 
       ' 0:<    Default : 0 
       ' 0:<    DeviceID : Glasgow-HP-colour 
       ' 0:<    Direct : 0 
       ' 0:<    DriverName : HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M476 PCL 6 
       ' 0:<    EnableBIDI : 0 
       ' 0:<    EnableDevQueryPrint : 0 
       ' 0:<    HorizontalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Local : -1 
       ' 0:<    Name : Glasgow-HP-colour 
       ' 0:<    Network : 0 
       ' 0:<    PortName : 10.20.2.10 
       ' 0:<    PrintJobDataType : RAW 
       ' 0:<    PrintProcessor : hpcpp155 
       ' 0:<    RawOnly : 0 
       ' 0:<    Shared : 0 
       ' 0:<    SpoolEnabled : -1 
       ' 0:<    VerticalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Caption : Bluebeam PDF 
       ' 0:<    Default : 0 
       ' 0:<    DeviceID : Bluebeam PDF 
       ' 0:<    Direct : 0 
       ' 0:<    DriverName : BluebeamPSDriver 
       ' 0:<    EnableBIDI : 0 
       ' 0:<    EnableDevQueryPrint : 0 
       ' 0:<    HorizontalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Local : -1 
       ' 0:<    Name : Bluebeam PDF 
       ' 0:<    Network : 0 
       ' 0:<    PortName : BLUEBEAMPDFPORT 
       ' 0:<    PrintJobDataType : RAW 
       ' 0:<    PrintProcessor : winprint 
       ' 0:<    RawOnly : 0 
       ' 0:<    Shared : 0 
       ' 0:<    SpoolEnabled : -1 
       ' 0:<    VerticalResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Caption : Adobe PDF 
       ' 0:<    Default : 0 
       ' 0:<    DeviceID : Adobe PDF 
       ' 0:<    Direct : 0 
       ' 0:<    DriverName : Adobe PDF Converter 
       ' 0:<    EnableBIDI : 0 
       ' 0:<    EnableDevQueryPrint : 0 
       ' 0:<    HorizontalResolution : 1200 
       ' 0:<    Local : -1 
       ' 0:<    Name : Adobe PDF 
       ' 0:<    Network : 0 
       ' 0:<    PortName : Documents\*.pdf 
       ' 0:<    PrintJobDataType : RAW 
       ' 0:<    PrintProcessor : winprint 
       ' 0:<    RawOnly : -1 
       ' 0:<    Shared : 0 
       ' 0:<    SpoolEnabled : -1 
       ' 0:<    VerticalResolution : 1200 
       ' 0:< PRINTER CONFIGURATION INFORMATION:  
       ' 0:<    Color : 1 
       ' 0:<    Description : Fax (redirected 31) 
       ' 0:<    DriverVersion : 1024 
       ' 0:<    Duplex : 0 
       ' 0:<    Orientation : 1 
       ' 0:<    PaperLength : 2970 
       ' 0:<    PaperSize : A4 210 x 297 mm 
       ' 0:<    PaperWidth : 2100 
       ' 0:<    PrintQuality : 200 
       ' 0:<    SpecificationVersion : 1025 
       ' 0:<    XResolution : 200 
       ' 0:<    YResolution : 200 
       ' 0:< PRINTER CONFIGURATION INFORMATION:  
       ' 0:<    Color : 2 
       ' 0:<    Copies : 1 
       ' 0:<    Description : Send To OneNote 2013 
       ' 0:<    DriverVersion : 1536 
       ' 0:<    Orientation : 1 
       ' 0:<    PaperLength : 2970 
       ' 0:<    PaperSize : A4 210 x 297 mm 
       ' 0:<    PaperWidth : 2100 
       ' 0:<    PrintQuality : 600 
       ' 0:<    SpecificationVersion : 1025 
       ' 0:<    XResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    YResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Color : 1 
       ' 0:<    Copies : 1 
       ' 0:<    Description : RICOH HEMEL 
       ' 0:<    DriverVersion : 8192 
       ' 0:<    Duplex : -1 
       ' 0:<    MediaType : 512 
       ' 0:<    Orientation : 1 
       ' 0:<    PaperLength : 2970 
       ' 0:<    PaperSize : A4 210 x 297 mm 
       ' 0:<    PaperWidth : 2100 
       ' 0:<    PrintQuality : 600 
       ' 0:<    SpecificationVersion : 1025 
       ' 0:<    XResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    YResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Color : 1 
       ' 0:<    Copies : 1 
       ' 0:<    Description : LONDON RICOH 
       ' 0:<    DriverVersion : 8192 
       ' 0:<    Duplex : 0 
       ' 0:<    MediaType : 512 
       ' 0:<    Orientation : 1 
       ' 0:<    PaperLength : 2970 
       ' 0:<    PaperSize : A4 210 x 297 mm 
       ' 0:<    PaperWidth : 2100 
       ' 0:<    PrintQuality : 600 
       ' 0:<    SpecificationVersion : 1025 
       ' 0:<    XResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    YResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Color : 2 
       ' 0:<    Copies : 1 
       ' 0:<    Description : HP Designjet T520 
       ' 0:<    DriverVersion : 1536 
       ' 0:<    MediaType : 1 
       ' 0:<    Orientation : 1 
       ' 0:<    PaperLength : 2794 
       ' 0:<    PaperSize : UNKNOWN 
       ' 0:<    PaperWidth : 2159 
       ' 0:<    PrintQuality : 600 
       ' 0:<    SpecificationVersion : 1025 
       ' 0:<    XResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    YResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Color : 2 
       ' 0:<    Copies : 1 
       ' 0:<    Description : Glasgow-HP-colour 
       ' 0:<    DriverVersion : 1536 
       ' 0:<    Duplex : 0 
       ' 0:<    MediaType : 291 
       ' 0:<    Orientation : 1 
       ' 0:<    PaperLength : 2970 
       ' 0:<    PaperSize : A4 210 x 297 mm 
       ' 0:<    PaperWidth : 2100 
       ' 0:<    PrintQuality : 600 
       ' 0:<    SpecificationVersion : 1025 
       ' 0:<    XResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    YResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Color : 2 
       ' 0:<    Copies : 1 
       ' 0:<    Description : Bluebeam PDF 
       ' 0:<    DriverVersion : 1536 
       ' 0:<    Orientation : 1 
       ' 0:<    PaperLength : 2970 
       ' 0:<    PaperWidth : 2099 
       ' 0:<    PrintQuality : 600 
       ' 0:<    SpecificationVersion : 1025 
       ' 0:<    XResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    YResolution : 600 
       ' 0:<    Color : 2 
       ' 0:<    Copies : 1 
       ' 0:<    Description : Adobe PDF 
       ' 0:<    DriverVersion : 1536 
       ' 0:<    Orientation : 1 
       ' 0:<    PaperLength : 2970 
       ' 0:<    PaperSize : A4 210 x 297 mm 
       ' 0:<    PaperWidth : 2100 
       ' 0:<    PrintQuality : 1200 
       ' 0:<    SpecificationVersion : 1025 
       ' 0:<    XResolution : 1200 
       ' 0:<    YResolution : 1200 
        ' 0:< ::1:: Delta VM: Avail +28 -> 8386712 MB, Used +9 -> 489 MB, Peak +8 -> 489 MB; RAM: Avail -6152 -> 144928 MB, Used +13 -> 415
   MB, Peak +12 -> 415 MB 
        'E 12-Nov-2015 12:37:26.470;   0:< 
        Jrn.Command "SystemMenu" , "Quit the application; prompts to save projects , ID_APP_EXIT"
       ' 0:< ::2:: Delta VM: Avail +111 -> 8386823 MB, Used -9 -> 481 MB, Peak +1 -> 490 MB; RAM: Avail -23 -> 144906 MB, Used -8 -> 407
   MB, Peak +1 -> 416 MB 
       ' 0:<  ->desktop ExitManagedInstance 
       ' 0:<  <-desktop ExitManagedInstance 
       ' 0:<  ->desktop ExitNativeInstance 
       ' 0:< API unregistering ApplicationClosing event by application Ribbon (dd5c37b2-1954-40d1-8be7-092cb5fd96f3). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering DocumentSaving event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering DocumentSavingAs event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering ViewActivating event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering DocumentPrinting event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering DocumentOpening event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering FileExporting event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering DocumentClosing event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering DocumentSynchronizingWithCentral event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering DocumentOpened event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API unregistering DocumentClosed event by application Excitech Toolkit (ff6d1d75-ae5b-405f-a1e2-06f737cc9a6f). 
       ' 0:< API_SUCCESS { Restoring command id 'ID_EXPORT_IFC' Executed implementation. } 
       ' 0:< API_SUCCESS { API unregistering command Export to IAI IFC (Industry Foundation Classes) file format Executed event by
   application IFC override (e78da2e3-7e89-464c-97cd-2212c8be3fa8). } 
       ' 0:< API unregistering DocumentClosing event by application Revit To Scia Engineer (3d711d95-8f37-4869-98f2-474a4924a89a). 
       ' 0:< Forcibly unregistering Updater with id:51c0be9b-07a8-443a-be8c-21db815b17e7 
       ' 0:< Forcibly removing all update triggers for all Updaters 
       ' 0:< Unregistering all external services. 
       ' 0:< ::2:: Delta VM: Avail +209 -> 8387033 MB, Used -203 -> 278 MB; RAM: Avail -2 -> 144904 MB, Used -10 -> 397 MB 
       'C 12-Nov-2015 12:37:28.435;   0:< License cleanup complete: 0, 0 
       ' 0:< Journal Exit 
       ' 0:< Log Summary 
       ' 0:< .Count 
       ' 0:< ...CloseHiddenWindowsInAllDocuments = 2 
       ' 0:< ...getADocuments_Arr = 649 
       ' 0:< ...onUpdateWindowCloseHidden = 2 
       ' 0:< ...PendingMessages = 97 
       ' 0:< Total session time spent reclaiming memory: 0.000000 seconds.  Averaged 0.000000 seconds/call for 0 calls. 
       ' 0:<               BackgroundLoader exec=     1 (parallel=     1)   
       ' 0:<                  FormOrAbandon exec=     1 (parallel=     0)   self=    0.000072 sec (avg=  0.000) 
       ' 0:<                 TaskFileExists exec=   218 (parallel=   211)   
       ' 0:<                 TaskWaitCursor exec=     1 (parallel=     1)   
       ' 0:< ::2:: Delta VM: Avail +29 -> 8387062 MB, Used -1 -> 277 MB; RAM: Avail +7 -> 144912 MB, Used -8 -> 389 MB 
       ' 0:<  <-desktop ExitNativeInstance 
       'C 12-Nov-2015 12:37:28.985;   0:< finished recording journal file
```

Comment: Identical hardware?

Comment: yes exact same machine.

Comment: You are loading Revit without any addins on both users?  Have you tried removing the user's profile from the machine?

Comment: I've copied all the addins from User A to User B and User B still loads quicker. Have not revamped profile, but id really like to know whats causing the problem for future reference.

Comment: I asked you to load it without addins

Comment: Sure how can I do that for only one user?

Comment: another interesting thing - I created a new user and have the same issue. Works if user is administrator.

Comment: Do both users have the same permissions?

Comment: no User B is administrator. If I remove administrative rights from User B it has the same issue, so most likely permissions, but not sure on what folder. Im using procmon.exe to monitor process.

Comment: So you have identified the cause.

Comment: yes but not a fix.

Comment: Hi Ramound, manage to load without addins and fond the problem. If you want to answer the question ill accept as answer.

Comment: All I did was suggest a basic troubleshooting step :$

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar issues with autocad for users on a domain controlled network.

Removing the user profile from the machine and reconnecting it has worked for us in the past.